# How to use Bootstrap Timeline to display Data in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

In my ASP.NET Application, I want to use the Bootstrap timeline to display an activity log in the application.I have been searching the internet a lot on how to use the Twitter Bootstrap timeline to display data in ASP.NET C# but couldn't find any. I understand the html behind it very well but don't know how to make it dynamic in fetching data.

I hope someone can please help me with ideas as to how I can solve this problem. Tutorial links will also be appreciated.

This is a link to the bootstrap timeline I am talking about. 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a call to your code behind page and return json. Next use jQuery or javascript to loop over that json to dynamically build the html that the timeline needs.

```
<ul id="myTimeline" class="timeline">
```

Add li tags in a loop. This would be a good use for something like Aurelia, knockout or angular. Otherwise just use javascript to append the li tags to the ul tag. The bootstrap timeline class will take care of the rest.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/yourURL",
    data: JSON.stringify({ yourPostData }),
    type: "Post",
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).then(function (data) {
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data.d);

   $.each(obj.timelineList, function(index, item) {
       $("#myTimeline").append("<li>" + item.timelineText + "</li>");
   });
});
```

Since there is alot of html that goes into each li tag this would be a good place for a template. Look into either the template tag or use:

```
<script type="html" id="myTemplate">
  ..your html
```